# Theme editor menu item refuses to go away

Tags: admin-menu

I've got an action set up on `admin_menu` to modify it as needed. I successfully removed the themes menu with the following:

```
remove_submenu_page('themes.php', 'themes.php');
```

Now I want to get rid of the useless yet dangerous theme editor.

```
remove_submenu_page('themes.php', 'theme-editor.php');
```

This refuses to work for whatever reason. I can remove any of the other appearance menu items but the theme editor refuses to listen to my demands.

That particular menu item is indeed added via `add_submenu_page` on line 163 of `wp-admin/menu.php` so I fail to see why I can't get rid of it.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: You can disable the the theme and plugin editor with `define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT',true)` in your config file.

Comment: @t31os could you please move that to an answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get rid of the theme editor but it also gets rid of the plugin editor.

Paste in your *wp-config.php*:
`define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true)`

Comment: You sure about this constant? I can't seem to find it in source or Codex.

Comment: t31os provided an answer inside the comments, this answer cites an apparently inexistant constant... so, made a merge...

Answer (score 0):

In WP 3.1, you should be able to use the `views_users` filter to limit the views displayed on the users page. The views are the horizontally arranged links to filter by role.